# Import com.googlecode.javacpp.BytePointer not working on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, javacv

I want to run an application on hadoop,in the application I have the following import: "import com.googlecode.javacpp.BytePointer".  After I run it on hadoop I get this:

```
13/09/09 15:58:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : 
     attempt_201309091557_0001_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
     Error: com/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer
```

Does anyone have an idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: I found that I get this because the included jars are not found.

Answer (score 0):

After I properly included the needed jars it worked.